# pymongo sorting after setting list of document as a variable

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, for-loop, pymongo

I recently found that .sort() in my code has been interrupted by my other code.
I want to list the set of documents posted in 30days and sort it in most liked order.
Previous work to this was to find all documents in all time so, my code had sorting with likes already and then I added period.

The problem is that my list is being sorted with likes within dates.
for example, the most liked document is listed under less liked document that has some likes but posted in more recent date.

Here is my code

```
@app.route('/api/list/monthly_hot', methods=['GET'])
def show_monthly_hot():
    fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
    today = datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Seoul'))
    all = list(db.collection.find({}, {'_id': False}).sort('like', -1))
    hot_posts = []
    for i in range(0, 30):
        target = today - timedelta(days=i)
        period = target.strftime(fmt)
        for x in all:
            if x['date'] == period:
                y = x
                hot_posts.append(y)
    return jsonify({'hot_posts': hot_posts})
```

So I tried to put .sort() in different variables

```
@app.route('/api/list/monthly_hot', methods=['GET'])
def show_monthly_hot():
    fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
    today = datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Seoul'))
    all = list(db.collection.find({}, {'_id': False}).sort('like', -1))
    hot_posts = [].sort('like', -1)
    for i in range(0, 30):
        target = today - timedelta(days=i)
        period = target.strftime(fmt)
        for x in all:
            if x['date'] == period:
                y = x.sort('like', -1)
                hot_posts.append(y).sort('like', -1)
    return jsonify({'hot_posts': hot_posts}).sort('like', -1)
```

= failed(tried one at a time, not all lines like the above)

I tried [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

```
@app.route('/api/list/monthly_hot', methods=['GET'])
def show_monthly_hot():
    fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
    today = datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Seoul'))
    all = list(db.collection.find({}, {'_id': False}).sort('like', -1))
    hot_posts = []
    for i in range(0, 30):
        target = today - timedelta(days=i)
        period = target.strftime(fmt)
        for x in all:
            if x['date'] == period:
                y = sorted(x, key=itemgetter('like'), reverse=True)
                hot_posts.append(y)
    return jsonify({'hot_posts': hot_posts})
```

= failed

Comment: I think you can apply the sort on the collection's find method's result. The find method returns a cursor, which can be converted to an array/list (check the cursor's methods). Then apply the sort on the resulting array/list of documents. The second way, is use an aggregate query where you can sort within the query itself  (on the db server).

Comment: i tried but could not find the solution so I worked with javascript after ajax success. which I put posts.sort(function(x, y){ return y.like - x.like; });. I looked into https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-sort/  and this worked! Thank you